# Meaning of onomatopoeia バン / ババン / バーン

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

Whilst reading Japanese manga, to assist me in learning, I frequently come across a few actions that I am completely unfamiliar with. (Section is circled in red):

[image: depicts scenario]

It even appears in fan art (this time differently):

[image: depicts scenario again, slightly differently]

Now I know that normally onomatopoeia like "SLASH" and "BANG" are depicted here, so maybe this is similar? Can someone tell me what this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

バン！/ ババン！/バーン！ is like "Ta-da! / Ta-dah!"

Comment: It should be noted that it's not something that a speaker would say, like we would do with "Ta-dah!"

To me, this SE is closer to "Bam!"  The author of this comic like to use バーン, ドーン and variants (like ババーン） when showing close=ups or entrances of characters, to get dramatic effect.