# シュバババーン?　What is it?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I initially heard this in this song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-Qu9rQDors

What is シュバババーン?　Seems like sound effect. When I search this exactly on google it has over a thousand results which means it wasn't a one time use in this song. The things I found searching it seemed dance related. I can understand the rest of the song but I wanted to clarify what the シュバババーン represents.

Answer (score 1):

シュバババ (or シュバババーン, etc) primarily represents a rapid-firing wind noise, like the sound of *shuriken* or punches thrown rapidly (see picture [here](https://hokuto.fandom.com/wiki/Hokuto_Hyakuretsu_Ken)).

In addition, it is also used pretty much in the same way as [シャキーン](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57439/5010), [ババーン](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23660/5010) or ジャーン. That is, シュババーン can be used to emphasize how energetic, cool, surprising or eye-catching someone/something is. In this case, "Tah-dah" in English is similar in purpose.